# Android: textview is null in Drawer when it is not showed

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, navigation-drawer

I have this problem:
I want to show a textview in the drawer header, and i want change this textview when the user open it, but when the textview is not displayed (he scrolldown the menu) that textview is NULL and the app is stopped (obviously).

```
 drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close){

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_time);
            long new_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long update = ((new_time - old_time) / 60000);
            if (update > 0 && update < 60) {
                t.setText("Updated " + update + " min. ago");
            } ...
```

This code works when the textview is displayed.

I put "if(t != null)", but it just make the app doesn't close itself. Can you show me a better solution?
Thanks!

Comment: try move ` t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_time);`
out of block `onDrawerOpened`

Comment: I did it, but doesn't works... :(

Answer (score 0):

```
t==null //because findViewById finds subview from which layout is showing.


t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_time);
```

means

```
t = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawer_time);//layout : which you can see from the screen.
```

you can try this:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null);
t = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_time);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to find `drawer_time` Textview from `drawer(DrawerLayout)`.

Change your line:

```
t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_time);
```

to

```
t = (TextView) drawer.findViewById(R.id.drawer_time);
```